# mongoose-attachments-aws2js upload directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-plugins

I have a schema for attachments:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var s3 = require('./config/secrets').s3;
var provider = require('mongoose-attachments-aws2js');
var attachments = require('mongoose-attachments');
attachments.registerStorageProvider('aws2js', provider);

var attachmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  date_created: {type: Date, default: new Date()},
  is_active: {type: Boolean, default: true}

});

attachmentSchema.plugin(attachments, {
  directory: 'HowToChangeThis',
  storage : {
    providerName: 'aws2js',
    options: {
      key: s3.key,
      secret: s3.secret,
      bucket: s3.bucket,
      acl: 'public-read'
    }
  },
  properties: {
    file: {
      styles: {
        original: {
          // keep the original file
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Attachment', attachmentSchema);
```

This schema is used within different docs: events (attachment is an event image), users (attachments is an avatar), location (attachment is a location photo), etc. 
But I don't want to upload all attachments to 1 remote directory. 
Is there any way to change mongoose-attachments-aws2js directory dynamically and keep only 1 schema for all attachments?